# SDL web8 - Issue with adding a website

Tags: web8

I'm trying to setup a web8 environment as per following [doc](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-52727C62-2976-476F-8F83-6A980DC585E7) and encountered following error while creating website through Add-TtmWebsite powershell cmdlet:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Add-TtmWebsite -Id StagingWebsite -CdEnvironmentId CDServerFarm01 -BaseUrls "http://10.100.101.153:85/" 
Add-TtmWebsite : Unable to save item of type 'WebApplicationData' with id 'StagingWebsite_RootWebApp'.
One or more errors occurred.
An error occurred while communicating with CD Discovery Service 'http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc' in CD Environment
 'CDServerFarm01'.
An error occurred while processing this request.
Path 'http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc/WebApplications' is not allowed
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-TtmWebsite -Id StagingWebsite -CdEnvironmentId CDServerFarm01 -BaseUrls "htt ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Tridion.Topolog...dWebsiteCommand:AddWebsiteCommand) [Add-TtmWebsite], Da
   taServiceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Tridion.TopologyManager.Automation.AddWebsiteCommand
```

Not sure why its complaining "http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc/WebApplications" is not allowed? At the moment i see my discovery service is up and accessible. What could be the reason for this issue and how to mitigate it. Appreciate your inputs!

Comment: How did this got fixed, I am also getting the error while adding the website.. PS C:\SDL\web\discovery\config> Add-TtmWebsite -Id visitorsweb -CdEnvironmentId SampleCD -BaseUrls http://localhost:82
Add-TtmWebsite : Unable to save item of type 'WebApplicationData' with id 'visitorsweb_RootWebApp'.
One or more errors occurred.
An error occurred while communicating with CD Discovery Service 'http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc' in CD
Environment 'SampleCD'.
An error occurred while processing this request.
Path 'http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc/WebCapabilities' is not allowed
At line:1 char:1
+

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/2408)

Comment: @Rafeeq, I converted your follow-up to a comment along with Hiren's note. Indeed this is better as a new question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most likely reason is that you have specified the wrong credentials when creating the CD environment. It needs to be a user in the "cm" role.

Check the credentials by calling `Get-TtmCdEnvironment` and verify that you are using the "cmuser" client ID.

To correct the credentials, you can call `Set-TtmCdEnvironment`:

```
Set-TtmCdEnvironment -Id YourEnvironmentId -AuthenticationType OAuth -ClientId cmuser -ClientSecret YourSecretHere
```

Comment: Actually, the Add-TtmCdEnvironment command failed, so the CdEnvironment entity is not created and hence you can't use Set-TtmCdEnvironment yet, but you can just retry the Add-TtmCdEnvironment command with the additional parameters.

Comment: Oh, wait... It's the Add-TtmWebsite command that failed.  In that case, I don't think the problem lies in the credentials (otherwise the Add-TtmCdEnvironment command would have failed already).

Comment: Thanks Peter, Rick for your inputs! Setting CdEnvironment with cmuser resolved the issue!!

Comment: @RickPannekoek I've seen it happen, when the credentials are valid but for a different user (registration or cduser). They can access the discovery service, but not the WebApplication path and such. 

Anyway, glad to hear it's fixed :)

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is probably that the WebCapability is not defined in you CD Environment's Discovery Service.

You probably didn't define any Capability yet; you first have to run the registration JAR in order to populate the Discovery Service's Capabilities from the cd_storage_conf.xml.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed as below:

- I ran command `java -jar discovery-registration.jar read`
- I had only token service capabilities enabled,
- I copied and updated All the roles from the installation configuration..
- Run `java -jar discovery-registration.jar Update`

Then ran the command
`Add-TtmWebsite -Id visitorsweb -CdEnvironmentId SampleCD -BaseUrls http://localhost:82`

Successfully created ..