# Error while Installing DXA 1.4 on SDL Web 8.1.1

Tags: dxa, web8, sdl-tridion

Error while Installing DXA 1.4 on Web 8.1.1

SDL WEB 8.1.1 Installed successfully.

Trying to install DXA 1.4 on SDL Web 8.1.1
Followed the steps described [here](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20DXA-v4&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-EDB49D8A-DCC3-45E7-B809-6A8B377C4FEA&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-EDB49D8A-DCC3-45E7-B809-6A8B377C4FEA.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-EDB49D8A-DCC3-45E7-B809-6A8B377C4FEA).

```
PS C:\Installation\SDL DXA .NET 1.4\cms> .\ttm-prepare.ps1
Get-TtmCdTopologyType : Authorization has been denied for this request.
At C:\Installation\SDL DXA .NET 1.4\cms\ttm-prepare.ps1:16 char:20
+ $cdTopologyTypes = Get-TtmCdTopologyType
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Tridion.Topolog...logyTypeCommand:GetCdTopologyTypeCommand) [Get-TtmCdTop
   ologyType], DataServiceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Tridion.TopologyManager.Automation.GetCdTopologyTypeCommand

Get-TtmCdTopology : Authorization has been denied for this request.
At C:\Installation\SDL DXA .NET 1.4\cms\ttm-prepare.ps1:17 char:17
+ $cdTopologies = Get-TtmCdTopology
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Tridion.Topolog...TopologyCommand:GetCdTopologyCommand) [Get-TtmCdTopolog
   y], DataServiceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Tridion.TopologyManager.Automation.GetCdTopologyCommand

Get-TtmCdEnvironment : Authorization has been denied for this request.
At C:\Installation\SDL DXA .NET 1.4\cms\ttm-prepare.ps1:18 char:19
+ $cdEnvironments = Get-TtmCdEnvironment
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Tridion.Topolog...ironmentCommand:GetCdEnvironmentCommand) [Get-TtmCdEnvi
   ronment], DataServiceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Tridion.TopologyManager.Automation.GetCdEnvironmentCommand

Get-TtmWebsite : Authorization has been denied for this request.
At C:\Installation\SDL DXA .NET 1.4\cms\ttm-prepare.ps1:19 char:13
+ $websites = Get-TtmWebsite
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Tridion.Topolog...tWebsiteCommand:GetWebsiteCommand) [Get-TtmWebsite], Da
   taServiceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Tridion.TopologyManager.Automation.GetWebsiteCommand

Add-TtmCdTopologyType : Authorization has been denied for this request.
At C:\Installation\SDL DXA .NET 1.4\cms\ttm-prepare.ps1:34 char:27
+         $cdTopologyType = Add-TtmCdTopologyType -Id $id -Name $name -Environment ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Tridion.Topolog...logyTypeCommand:AddCdTopologyTypeCommand) [Add-TtmCdTop
   ologyType], DataServiceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Tridion.TopologyManager.Automation.AddCdTopologyTypeCommand

CD Topology Type registered with Id 'StagingOnly' and Name 'DXA Staging Only'.
Add-TtmCdTopologyType : Authorization has been denied for this request.
At C:\Installation\SDL DXA .NET 1.4\cms\ttm-prepare.ps1:34 char:27
+         $cdTopologyType = Add-TtmCdTopologyType -Id $id -Name $name -Environment ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Tridion.Topolog...logyTypeCommand:AddCdTopologyTypeCommand) [Add-TtmCdTop
   ologyType], DataServiceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Tridion.TopologyManager.Automation.AddCdTopologyTypeCommand

CD Topology Type registered with Id 'StagingLive' and Name 'DXA Staging/Live'.
Please provide information for the 'Staging' CD Environment:
        Enter Discovery Service URL (leave empty if you don't want to configure it):
PS C:\Installation\SDL DXA .NET 1.4\cms>
```

Topology service URL are working fine.
http://localhost:81/ttm201501

```
{
  "@odata.context":"http://localhost:81/ttm201501/$metadata","value":[
    {
      "name":"CdTopologyTypes","kind":"EntitySet","url":"CdTopologyTypes"
    },{
      "name":"CdEnvironments","kind":"EntitySet","url":"CdEnvironments"
    },{
      "name":"CdTopologies","kind":"EntitySet","url":"CdTopologies"
    },{
      "name":"CmEnvironments","kind":"EntitySet","url":"CmEnvironments"
    },{
      "name":"Websites","kind":"EntitySet","url":"Websites"
    },{
      "name":"WebApplications","kind":"EntitySet","url":"WebApplications"
    },{
      "name":"Mappings","kind":"EntitySet","url":"Mappings"
    },{
      "name":"ScopedTopologyItems","kind":"EntitySet","url":"ScopedTopologyItems"
    }
  ]
}
```

I was tried with domain user but administrator on the system.

I tried added my account and MTSUser to Topology Manager Administrators Usergroup still no luck.

And then tried cms-import script that also not success due to topology was not created.

```
016/04/29 00:24:28 <10> [Error] Tridion.ContentManager.InvalidPropertyValueException: Invalid value for property 'CdTo
pologyTypeId'. Cd Topology Type with id 'StagingOnly' does not exist.
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.BusinessProcessType.OnSaved(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Process.<>c__DisplayClass2.<InvokeInErrorHandler>b__1(Boolean isRetry)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.AbortErrorHandler.Invoke[T](Func`2 function, LocalizableMessage message, Bool
ean retryAvailable, Boolean isCritical, UserReply additionalUserReplyOptions)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Process.InvokeInErrorHandler[T](Func`2 function, LocalizableMessage message,
Boolean retryAvailable, Boolean isCritical)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.ImportAction.SaveItem(IdentifiableObject item, IdentifiableObjectData deltaOb
ject)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.CreateImportAction.Perform(IdentifiableObjectData itemData)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.ImportItem(WebDavUrl exportUrl, IList`1 dependentItemsChain, Diction
ary`2 unresolvedDependencies, Boolean specialImport)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.ImportItem(WebDavUrl exportUrl, IList`1 dependentItemsChain, Diction
ary`2 unresolvedDependencies, Boolean specialImport)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.ImportItem(WebDavUrl exportUrl, IList`1 dependentItemsChain, Diction
ary`2 unresolvedDependencies, Boolean specialImport)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.ImportItem(WebDavUrl exportUrl, IList`1 dependentItemsChain, Diction
ary`2 unresolvedDependencies, Boolean specialImport)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.ImportItems(IList`1 items, Boolean specialGroupImport)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.Import(String packageName)
2016/04/29 00:24:28 <10> [Information] Transactional import failed at 4/29/2016 12:24:28 AM. No changes were committed
to SDL Web Content Manager.
An error occured while importing 'C:\Installation\SDL DXA .NET 1.4\cms\web8\all-publications.zip'
At C:\Installation\SDL DXA .NET 1.4\ImportExport\ContentManagerUtils.ps1:402 char:9
+         throw "An error occured while importing '$packageFullPath'"
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (An error occure...blications.zip':String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : An error occured while importing 'C:\Installation\SDL DXA .NET 1.4\cms\web8\all-publication
```

If anybody based this issue, please adise

Comment: Seeing Authorization errors, can you please check http://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/14181/1743 and see if the steps provided there helps resolving this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Fixed this issue by setting the some [security to use Topology Manager](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v1&lang=en-US#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-91490B86-147D-4D2F-BCFF-073138FA2130.xml&docid=GUID-91490B86-147D-4D2F-BCFF-073138FA2130&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-91490B86-147D-4D2F-BCFF-073138FA2130) commands. It seems that there are some local groups which we need to be a member of in order to use these commands.

add-user-to-groups

[image]

And then Rebooted the server issue has been fixed.