# 403 status while calling Add-TtmWebsite

Tags: topology-manager

When running the following script on SDL Web 8 CU1 ...

```
import-module Tridion.TopologyManager.Automation
Add-TtmCdEnvironment -Id localStagingEnvironment `
            -EnvironmentPurpose Staging `
            -DiscoveryEndpointUrl http://localhost:9082/discovery.svc `
            -AuthenticationType OAuth -ClientId cduser `
            -ClientSecret CDUserP@ssw0rd 
Add-TtmWebsite -Id stagingVisitorsWeb `
            -CdEnvironmentId localStagingEnvironment `
            -BaseUrls http://staging.visitorsweb.local
```

I get this error:

```
Add-TtmWebsite : Unable to save item of type 'WebApplicationData' with id 
                                                     'stagingVisitorsWeb_RootWebApp'.
One or more errors occurred.
An error occurred while communicating with CD Discovery Service
        'http://localhost:9082/discovery.svc' in CD Environment 'localStagingEnvironment'. 
Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).
```

Following the advice [here](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/13738/129), I have been able to verify that the discovery service accepts a token created using the credentials used when creating the environment. So far the logs haven't given me any great insights.

What can cause this problem? How can I further investigate? Which logs should I look in, and what should I look for?

Update: The Web Capability is registered. On running the registration tool, I see this in the output:

```
WebCapability{id='DefaultWeb', lastUpdateTime=1460141689675}
```

and afterwards I still have the problem.

Comment: Can you please check that your DiscoveryService has WebCapability registered? It is not there by default. You need to run discovey-registration tool first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use cmuser instead of cduser as OAuth ClientId; cduser is intended to be used by the Web Application and has fewer permissions than cmuser.

See [SDL web8 - Issue with adding a website](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/13706/sdl-web8-issue-with-adding-a-website/13708#13708)