# Error while running .\ttm-prepare.ps1 script DXA 1.4 on SDL Web 8.1.1

Tags: dxa, web8

Error:

```
PS C:\Installation\SDL DXA .NET 1.4\cms> .\ttm-prepare.ps1
Enter DXA 'Staging' Website Base URL(s): http://dxastaging.sdlweb8.indi
Add-TtmWebsite : Unable to save item of type 'WebApplicationData' with id 'Website1_RootWebApp'.
One or more errors occurred.
An error occurred while communicating with CD Discovery Service 'http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc' in CD
Environment 'CdEnvironment1'.
An error occurred while processing this request.
Path 'http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc/WebCapabilities' is not allowed
At C:\Installation\SDL DXA .NET 1.4\cms\ttm-prepare.ps1:112 char:24
+             $website = Add-TtmWebsite -CdEnvironmentId $cdEnvironment.Id -BaseUr ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Tridion.Topolog...dWebsiteCommand:AddWebsiteCommand) [Add-TtmWebsite], Da
   taServiceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Tridion.TopologyManager.Automation.AddWebsiteCommand
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use cmuser with `Ttm-AddWebsite`, as noted in [this answer from Rick](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/14388/129).

If this doesn't help, it's likely that you haven't registered the WebCapability. So check that it's correctly set up in the `cd_storage_conf.xml` (probably of your discovery service) and that you have run the update:

```
java -jar discovery-registration.jar update
```

Comment: Thanks Dominic!, It's working fine. It was missed out the WebCapability Role in the cd_storage_confi.xml